# How to reference argument values of PostgreSQL procedures inside SQL statements such as REASSIGN OWNED?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to recreate several databases and users executing SQL file via psql.exe. And I don't want to switch to `createuser` and similar tools.

Here is my input file to `psql`. I have deliberately changed the `LANGUAGE` to non-existent `PSQL` to emphasize that I'm trying to run it using `psql` (from a batch file). This is a bit pseudocode but you get the point. The SQL or pgplsql languages solve nothing, the error is the same: postgres uses `username` as a value to the `REASSIGN OWNED` instead of `user456`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_database_and_user(
  dbName character varying,
  username character varying,
  password character varying)
AS $$
  REASSIGN OWNED BY username TO postgres;
  DROP OWNED BY username;

  -- ...other statements...

  \connect "dbname=${dbName} user=${username} password=${password}"
$$ LANGUAGE PSQL;


CALL create_database_and_user('db123', 'user456', 'p@ss');
```

It doesn't work

```
psql:./initdb.sql:14: ERROR:  language "psql" does not exist
psql:./initdb.sql:17: ERROR:  role "username" does not exist
CONTEXT:  SQL function "create_database_and_user" statement 1
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because `REASSIGN OWNED` does not work with prepared statements, which implies that you cannot use it with parameters in a function.

You'll have to use [dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) for that:

```
EXECUTE format('REASSIGN OWNED BY %I TO postgres',
               username);
```